# Figuring EasyVer problems - problems whose witness can be verified in time independent on the instance size

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, complexity-classes

In [a related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21409/what-relations-are-there-between-a-problem-hardness-and-the-hardness-of-verifyin) I've defined a class of graph problems which are verifiable using a time related only on the size of the witness:

$EasyVer=\{L\subset \mathcal{G}\times \mathbb{N}| $ a witness $w$ of $L$'s instance can be verified in $poly(k)$ time$\}$, i.e. independent of $|V|,|E|$.

You can assume that the verifier has random access to the graph adjacency matrix in $O(1)$ time.

Examples for $EasyVer$ problems will be $VC, Clique, IS$ and $Steiner Tree$.

Also, many packing and problems, $triangle-packing$, $k-path-packing$, or in general $H-packing$ for a graph $H$ with constant treewidth, are all in $EasyVer$.

Problems which aren't in (i.e. require more extensive interaction with the input) are also easily found: $VC, DominatingSet, FVS$(Feedback Vertex Set).

In order to get a sense of how $EasyVer$ relates to known complexity classes it would be useful to have a list of problem it contains.

**Which other NP-complete problem (or even better, problem classes) can be verified in $poly(k)$ time, where $k$ is the size of the problem witness?**

Comment: Is the verifier a [word RAM](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/slides/afapa08.pdf)? $\:$ If no, how do you show that $Clique$ and $IS$ are in $EasyVer$? $\;\;$ Even if the machine allows Random Access _with the target provided as a given slice of a tape_, I don't see any way, other than the verifier being a word RAM, to make verification run in less than $\:k\cdot \Omega(\log(\log(|V|)))\:$ time. $\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer - you can assume that the verifier has random access to the graph adjacency table, I've edited the question.

Comment: That doesn't resolve my issue, since I don't see a way for anything other than a word RAM to _even select the target entry_ (for random access) in less than $\Omega(\log(\log(|V|)))$ time. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, perhaps we should then go back to my previuous question, where I asked what's the right way to define this class: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21409/what-relations-are-there-between-a-problem-hardness-and-the-hardness-of-verifyin.

Comment: One could specify that the verifier receives the adjacency matrix of a [vertex-induced subgraph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-InducedSubgraph.html), but not the rest of the original adjacency matrix. $\;$

Comment: You can resolve that issue by using an input-dependent verifier, i.e. a NTM whose alphabet/transitions depend on the input. See my reply below.

Comment: @Super8 : $\:$ I'm fairly confident that such input-dependent verifiers would need to have Random Access, which would make them just a special case of word RAMs. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Well, it depends what you mean by "word RAM". Technically, as the verifier is input-dependent you can encode the input directly in the machine states, hence no need for a random access to an external input.

Comment: Maybe you could specify in more detail what you mean by $k$-clique being verifiable in poly($k$) time?  My first take was "but that's in $\Omega(n^k)$", and even after reading the comments above I remain confused about your model of computation.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you are interested in those parameterized problems that can be verified by a bounded-time NTM (running in time $f(k)$ for some function of the parameter). Up to fpt-reduction, these are precisely the problems in the class $W[1]$, see "On the parameterized complexity of short computation and factorization" by Cai, Chen, Downey and Fellows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer.
FVS for example is even FPT, but it doesn't seem you can verify a feedback set without looking at all of the graph.

Comment: That's why I wrote "up to fpt-reduction", as $W[1]$ can defined as the class of problems fpt-reducible to _Short Nondeterministic Turing machine Computation_. If you focus on bounded-time verification, it may be possible to define a variant of $W[1]$ using a different type of reduction...